# Example of a subgroup that is not normal (not involving permutations)

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

It would be great if someone could give me an example of a group such that the following happens

> a $\equiv$ b (mod N) and c $\equiv$  d (mod N) but ac $\not\equiv$ bd (mod N)

where N is a subgroup of a group G and a $\in$ G and b $\in$ G

a $\equiv$ b (mod N) iff $ab^{-1}$ $\in N$.

I saw an example of in the $S_n$, however I want to see one more concrete example to help me form better intuition.

Comment: Think about the subgroup generated by a reflection in a dihedral group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $G:=\mathbb{D}_4$ it is generated by a rotation $R$ and an axial symmetry $s$.

You know that $R^4=1$ and $sRs^{-1}=R^3$ and $s^2=1$.

Now we take $N:=<s>$. We set :

$$a:=c:=R \text{ and }b:=d:=Rs$$

Then :

$$a=c \text{ mod } N$$

$$b=d \text{ mod } N$$

But, on the other hand :
$$ac=R^2 \text{ and }bd= RsRs= RR^3=R^4=1$$

Of course $ac\notin N$.